# Can you build a rain diverter with a double T and a toilet plunger?

Tags: plumbing, drainage, downspout

I'm reading the GrowNYC [Rainwater Harvesting Guide](https://www.grownyc.org/files/osg/RainwaterManual_2018_FINAL_HighRes.pdf) and I see in the diagram a "winterizing tee" - a double tee with a reference to a plunger.  Are they really just talking about a toilet plunger or is there some other thing that will redirect/block flow on a 4" pipe that's called a plunger?  If it's actually a plunger, do you remove the handle?  Or would keeping the handle keep alignment better?

[image]

Comment: They use a plunger, but anything that would block the flow will work.  In winter might want something to block the path to the tank also, just in case of of ice blockage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen regular  plungers used in systems like this to divert water into swimming pools, spa, etc. a regular toilet plunger. The stick is too long to fit into the piping system but the ones I've seen had the stick cut down enough to fit into the system... It will add stability to the plunger.
The tee was a IPEX Sewer and Drain 4 In. Solvent Weld PVC Cross  and the plug was just a 4" test plug. The tee didn't have any threads. There are different types of plungers so get the tee first and then match the plunger to it. The system I've seen diverted almost all of the water. In some cases, the plungers were weighted down with some rocks because Florida's got heavy rain. You might have to trim the plunger too.

Comment: does it usually divert all the water or just some percentage of it?  and what is the "Tee" called, is it a double sanitary and does it normally have a cap or clean out via threading?

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey  Edited my answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your provided diagrams show what certainly looks like the head of a toilet plunger with the handle removed. That would be needed for it to fit in the "T".  There is nothing that is used for that specific purpose that is called a "plunger".  I believe that they are showing easy to obtain objects to complete the project. There are "plugs" that are available to close off various size drain piping, but they are more expensive than just buying a plunger.

Comment: would it be better just to add a ball valve lever instead of a plunger?  I think I can pay the extra $50... or is the shape of the plunger somehow better for overflow situations or debris?

Comment: I would use the materials that are recommended rather than over engineer the project.

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey that would be a whole 'nuther question, but I'd suggest that the valves would be much more efficient at redirecting water, would allow you to use a simple Tee (with a valve on each output end), and would be a lot easier to operate than reaching in and wrestling out a plunger head. The plunger would be a lot cheaper.